# Randomize a column from an specific row number

Tags: r

I would like to create a new column in my matrix that contains column number 1 but only randomizing from row 283 to row 730. Any ideas?

Comment: `m[,1][c(1:282, sample(283:730), 731:NROW(m))]`

Comment: To sample with replacement, use @d.b with `sample(283:730, 448, TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, if your data frame is df, then:

```
numbers<-c(1:282,sample(283:730),731:nrow(df))
df<-df[numbers,]
```